# Are there known NP-complete problems, neither NP-hard in the strong sense nor having pseudopolynomial algorithm?

Tags: ds.algorithms, np-hardness, np

In their [paper](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~plaisted/comp750/Strong-NP-completness.pdf) (p. 503) Garey and Johnson remark:

> ... there could exist an NP-complete problem which is neither NP-complete in the strong sense nor solvable by a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm ...

Does anyone know some candidate problems with the properties the mentioned above?

*I think the possible answer to this question can be a list of NP-complete problems in the ordinary sense such that no pseudopolynomial algorithm is known for them.*

Comment: Isn’t it possible to make up an artificial example by combining an NP-complete problem with a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm and an NP-intermediate language from Ladner’s theorem?

Comment: My answer posted earlier was incorrect; my apologies. This is what happens when I hand-wave and post!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I do not know if you are interested in hearing more detail of my comment on your question, but here is more detail anyway.

If P=NP, every problem in NP can be solved in polynomial time and therefore in pseudo-polynomial time, which means that no problem satisfies your requirement, as Magnus noted in his answer.  So assume P≠NP in the rest of this answer.

Because P≠NP, there exists a language *L*∈NP∖P which is not NP-complete (Ladner’s theorem).  Consider the following problem:

**Direct product of Partition and *L***
*Instance*: *m* positive integers *a*<sub>1</sub>, …, *a*<sub>*m*</sub> and *k* integers *b*<sub>1</sub>, …, *b*<sub>*k*</sub>∈{0,1}.
*Question*: Do both of the following hold?
(1) The *m* integers *a*<sub>1</sub>, …, *a*<sub>*m*</sub> form a yes-instance of the Partition problem.
(2) The *k*-bit string *b*<sub>1</sub>…*b*<sub>*k*</sub> belongs to *L*.

Following the paper by Garey and Johnson, define the Length function as *m*+⌈log max<sub>*i*</sub> *a*<sub>*i*</sub>⌉+*k* and the Max function as max<sub>*i*</sub> *a*<sub>*i*</sub>.

It is a routine to check (i) that it is NP-complete in the weak sense, (ii) that it does not have a pseudo-polynomial-time algorithm, and (iii) that it is not NP-complete in the strong sense.

(Hints: (i) Membership to NP follows from the fact that both the Partition problem and *L* are in NP.  For NP-hardness, reduce Partition to this problem.  (ii) Construct a pseudo-polynomial transformation from *L* to this problem.  (iii) Construct a pseudo-polynomial transformation from this problem to *L* by using the fact that Partition has a pseudo-polynomial-time algorithm.)

There is nothing special about the Partition problem in this construction: you can use your favorite weakly NP-complete problem with a pseudo-polynomial-time algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was more interested in non-artificial problems contrary to the one described by you. Though I'm in doubt concerning the definition of a non-artificial problem.

Comment: @Oleksandr: As for the choice of L, you can use any NP-intermediate language.  However, you are right that no matter which language L you choose, this construction gives an artificial problem because of taking the direct product with Partition.  I do not know of any natural problem satisfying your requirement.

Comment: Anyway, your answer is interesting for me and deserves upvote.

Comment: (Edit: Nevermind. :))

Answer (score 1):

I would say the answer is clearly no (that is, no one knows), because no one knows whether the NP-complete problems can be solved in *polynomial* time, let alone *pseudo*-polynomial time. (Every polynomial algorithm is, of course, pseudopolynomial.) If you can find a problem in NPC that cannot be solved in pseudopolynomial time, you have just proven that P≠NP, so I think it’s safe to say that no such examples will be produced any time soon.

Comment: I've edited my question to "Does anyone know some candidate problems ... ?"