# Intermediate $\mathsf{NP}$-complete problems?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, partition-problem

Partition problem is weakly NP-complete since it has polynomial (pseudo-polynomial) time algorithm if input integers are bounded by some polynomial. However, 3-Partition is strongly NP-complete problem even if input integers are bounded by a polynomial.

> **Assuming, $\mathsf{P \ne NP}$, Can we prove that intermediate NP-complete problems must exist? If the answer is yes, Is there such "natural" candidate problem?**

Here, Intermediate NP-complete problem is a problem that neither has a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm nor NP-complete in the strong sense.

I guess that there is an infinite hierarchy of intermediate NP-complete problems between weak NP-completeness and strong NP-completeness.

**EDIT March 6th**: As mentioned in the comments, an alternative way to pose the question is:

> **Assuming, $\mathsf{P \ne NP}$, Can we prove the existence of NP-complete problems that neither have polynomial time algorithm nor NP-complete when the numerical
>   inputs are presented in unary? If the answer is yes, Is there such "natural" candidate problem?**

**EDIT2 March 6**: The reverse direction of the implication is true. The existence of such "intermediate" $NP$-complete problems implies $\mathsf{P \ne NP}$ since if $\mathsf{ P=NP}$ then unary $NP$-complete problems are in $P$.

Comment: I think putting a restriction on the value of the numbers in Partition should do it.

Comment: Just a clarification (I'm not an expert): does the *definition* of strong/weak NP-completeness allow intermediate degrees? I.e. doesn't "strongly NPC" means "not weakly NPC" and vice versa?

Comment: similar to [ladner's thm](http://oldblog.computationalcomplexity.org/media/ladner.pdf) which states [iiuc] that if P$\neq$NP then NP hard problems (then superpolynomial time) must exist that are not NP complete (the so-called NPI, NP-intermediate class?). however something seems wrong with question. NPI is a defined class & its not nec the same as NP complete right? so an "intermediate NP complete" problem does not seem to make sense directly....

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi There is another definition of strong NP-completeness (may be less popular one) which defines a number problem to be NP-complete even if all input integers are represented in unary notation.

Comment: @vzn this is a ridiculous comment! 1) ladner's thm is not about np hard problems that are not np complete; 2) while Mohammad is sort of overloading terminology, he defines his class of problems clearly (NPC, not strongly NPC and no pseudopoly time algorithm) and it is different from NPC.

Comment: [NPI/ladners thm, wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate) sorry, stated it wrong, its a little subtle and predicated on the P=?NP conjecture. try again: NPI problems exist and are weaker than NP hard/NP complete and harder than P if P$\neq$NP? anyway suggest Mohammeds use of the word "intermediate" wrt NP/NP complete is problematic & inconsistent because NPI has already been defined.

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany: ok thanks, perhaps I suggest you to call it *unary NP-completeness* like [in Garey and Johnson "Strong" NP-Completeness Results: Motivation, Examples, and Implications](http://cs.unc.edu/~plaisted/comp750/Strong-NP-completness.pdf). So you are searching intermediate problems between unary NPC and pseudopolynomial NPC. I'm still trying to grasp it, however, in their paper, G&J say (about unary NPC): " ... It is not hard to see that this corresponds to our notion of strong NP-completeness ...".

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi I think the idea is that we can (->) given a binary number of size polynomial in the input, convert it to unary in polytime and run the unary algorithm, (<-) given a unary input of length poly in the rest of the input, read the whole thing and convert it to binary and run the binary algorithm.

Comment: Since any problem that has a polynomial-time algorithm if one of the input parameters is fixed is in FPT, you seem to be essentially asking whether there are problems harder than FPT but not W[1]-hard.  As far as I know Ladner's theorem can be extended to this setting; it might be in the Flum/Grohe textbook.

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer that only gives a candidate intermediate $NP$-complete problem.

$k$-Equal Sum Subsets problem: Given a multiset of $n$ positive integers $A = \{a_1,...,a_n\}$, are there $k$ nonempty disjoint subsets $S_1,...,S_k ⊆ \{a_1,...,a_n\}$ such that $sum(S_1) = ... = sum(S_k)$?

The problem is weakly $NP$-complete when $k= O(1)$ and therefore has pseudo-polynomial time algorithm for any fixed constant integer $k > 2$. However, it becomes strongly $NP$-complete when the number of equal sum subsets $k= \Omega(n)$.

If $k= \omega(1)$ and $k= O(\log n)$ then $k$-Equal Sum Subsets problem is a candidate intermediate $NP$-complete problem (as described in the question). This problem is neither known to have a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm nor proven to be $NP$-complete in the strong sense.

Reference:

CIELIEBAK, EIDENBENZ, PAGOURTZIS, and SCHLUDE, ON THE COMPLEXITY OF VARIATIONS OF EQUAL SUM SUBSETS, Nordic Journal of Computing 14(2008), 151–172

Comment: Have you seen this http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/7427/15637 ?

Comment: Yes. That answer provides  arguably an artificial problem.